# Sagemaker Studio UnkownServiceError for Session

Tags: session, amazon-sagemaker

When I run the following code in Sagemaker Studio, I get the `UnknownServiceError`:

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()
```

Any advice to overcome this would be greatly appreciated.

The error message in the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownServiceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2d2ae2d1e577> in <module>
      1 import boto3
      2 import sagemaker
----> 3 sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
      4 role = get_execution_role()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in __init__(self, boto_session, sagemaker_client, sagemaker_runtime_client, sagemaker_featurestore_runtime_client, default_bucket)
    124             sagemaker_client=sagemaker_client,
    125             sagemaker_runtime_client=sagemaker_runtime_client,
--> 126             sagemaker_featurestore_runtime_client=sagemaker_featurestore_runtime_client,
    127         )
    128 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _initialize(self, boto_session, sagemaker_client, sagemaker_runtime_client, sagemaker_featurestore_runtime_client)
    164         else:
    165             self.sagemaker_featurestore_runtime_client = self.boto_session.client(
--> 166                 "sagemaker-featurestore-runtime"
    167             )
    168 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py in client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    261             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    262             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
--> 263             aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
    264 
    265     def resource(self, service_name, region_name=None, api_version=None,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    833             is_secure=use_ssl, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, verify=verify,
    834             credentials=credentials, scoped_config=self.get_scoped_config(),
--> 835             client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
    836         monitor = self._get_internal_component('monitor')
    837         if monitor is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url, verify, credentials, scoped_config, api_version, client_config)
     76             'choose-service-name', service_name=service_name)
     77         service_name = first_non_none_response(responses, default=service_name)
---> 78         service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)
     79         cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
     80         endpoint_bridge = ClientEndpointBridge(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _load_service_model(self, service_name, api_version)
    114     def _load_service_model(self, service_name, api_version=None):
    115         json_model = self._loader.load_service_model(service_name, 'service-2',
--> 116                                                      api_version=api_version)
    117         service_model = ServiceModel(json_model, service_name=service_name)
    118         return service_model

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py in _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    130         if key in self._cache:
    131             return self._cache[key]
--> 132         data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    133         self._cache[key] = data
    134         return data

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py in load_service_model(self, service_name, type_name, api_version)
    376             raise UnknownServiceError(
    377                 service_name=service_name,
--> 378                 known_service_names=', '.join(sorted(known_services)))
    379         if api_version is None:
    380             api_version = self.determine_latest_version(

UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'sagemaker-featurestore-runtime'. Valid service names are: accessanalyzer, acm, acm-pca, alexaforbusiness, amplify, apigateway, apigatewaymanagementapi, apigatewayv2, appconfig, application-autoscaling, application-insights, appmesh, appstream, appsync, athena, autoscaling, autoscaling-plans, backup, batch, braket, budgets, ce, chime, cloud9, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codeartifact, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codeguru-reviewer, codeguruprofiler, codepipeline, codestar, codestar-connections, codestar-notifications, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, comprehend, comprehendmedical, compute-optimizer, config, connect, connectparticipant, cur, dataexchange, datapipeline, datasync, dax, detective, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dlm, dms, docdb, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ebs, ec2, ec2-instance-connect, ecr, ecs, efs, eks, elastic-inference, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, fms, forecast, forecastquery, frauddetector, fsx, gamelift, glacier, globalaccelerator, glue, greengrass, groundstation, guardduty, health, honeycode, iam, imagebuilder, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, iot-jobs-data, iot1click-devices, iot1click-projects, iotanalytics, iotevents, iotevents-data, iotsecuretunneling, iotsitewise, iotthingsgraph, ivs, kafka, kendra, kinesis, kinesis-video-archived-media, kinesis-video-media, kinesis-video-signaling, kinesisanalytics, kinesisanalyticsv2, kinesisvideo, kms, lakeformation, lambda, lex-models, lex-runtime, license-manager, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, macie, macie2, managedblockchain, marketplace-catalog, marketplace-entitlement, marketplacecommerceanalytics, mediaconnect, mediaconvert, medialive, mediapackage, mediapackage-vod, mediastore, mediastore-data, mediatailor, meteringmarketplace, mgh, migrationhub-config, mobile, mq, mturk, neptune, networkmanager, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, outposts, personalize, personalize-events, personalize-runtime, pi, pinpoint, pinpoint-email, pinpoint-sms-voice, polly, pricing, qldb, qldb-session, quicksight, ram, rds, rds-data, redshift, rekognition, resource-groups, resourcegroupstaggingapi, robomaker, route53, route53domains, route53resolver, s3, s3control, sagemaker, sagemaker-a2i-runtime, sagemaker-runtime, savingsplans, schemas, sdb, secretsmanager, securityhub, serverlessrepo, service-quotas, servicecatalog, servicediscovery, ses, sesv2, shield, signer, sms, sms-voice, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, sso, sso-oidc, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, synthetics, textract, transcribe, transfer, translate, waf, waf-regional, wafv2, workdocs, worklink, workmail, workmailmessageflow, workspaces, xray
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and `pip install sagemaker -U` (to 2.20.0) resolved it for me, hopefully that's all you need to get around this.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the issue on my side as well!